# Doctrine2: Bounded Contexts of the Entity and SINGLE_TABLE inheritance mapping. Kinda confused on am I doing it the right way

Tags: php, doctrine, domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

Long story short.

I use Doctrine's Single Table Inheritance mapping to map three different contexts (classes) of the one common entity: **NotActivatedCustomer**, **DeletedCustomer**, and **Customer**. Also, there is an **AbstractCustomer** which contains the next:

```yaml
App\Identity\Domain\Customer\AbstractCustomer:
  type: entity
  inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
  discriminatorColumn:
    name: discr
    type: string
  discriminatorMap:
    Customer: App\Identity\Domain\Customer\Customer
    NotActivatedCustomer: App\Identity\Domain\Customer\NotActivatedCustomer
    DeletedCustomer: App\Identity\Domain\Customer\DeletedCustomer
  table: customer
  id:
    id:
      type: customer_id
      unique: true
      generator:
        strategy: CUSTOM
      customIdGenerator:
        class: Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\IdGenerator\UuidV4Generator
  fields:
    email:
      type: email
      length: 180
      unique: true
```

A Subtype definition example:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Identity\Domain\Customer;

use App\Identity\Domain\User\Email;

class DeletedCustomer extends AbstractCustomer
{
    public const TYPE = 'DeletedCustomer';

    public function __construct(CustomerId $id)
    {
        $this->_setId($id);
        $this->_setEmail(new Email(sprintf('%s@mail.local', $id->value())));
    }
}
```

The Use Case:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Identity\Application\Customer\UseCase\DeleteCustomer;

use App\Identity\Application\Customer\CustomerEntityManager;
use App\Identity\Application\User\AuthenticatedCustomer;
use App\Identity\Domain\Customer\DeletedCustomer;
use App\Shared\Application\ImageManager;

final class DeleteCustomerHandler
{
    private CustomerEntityManager $customerEntityManager;
    private AuthenticatedCustomer $authenticatedCustomer;
    private ImageManager $imageManager;

    public function __construct(AuthenticatedCustomer $authenticatedCustomer,
                                CustomerEntityManager $customerEntityManagerByActiveTenant,
                                ImageManager $customerPhotoManager)
    {
        $this->customerEntityManager = $customerEntityManagerByActiveTenant;
        $this->authenticatedCustomer = $authenticatedCustomer;
        $this->imageManager = $customerPhotoManager;
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        $customer = $this->authenticatedCustomer->customer();

        $photo = (string) $customer->photo();

        $deletedCustomer = new DeletedCustomer($customer->id());

        // TODO OR return DeletedCustomer that way
        // $deletedCustomer = $customer->deactive();

        //  entityManager->merge() called here
        $this->customerEntityManager->sync($deletedCustomer);

        // simple entityManager->flush() under the hood
        $this->customerEntityManager->update();

        // that's a raw query to update discriminator field, hackish way I'm using
        // UPDATE customer SET discr = ? WHERE id = ?
        $this->customerEntityManager->updateInheritanceType($customer, DeletedCustomer::TYPE);

        if ($photo) {
            $this->imageManager->remove($photo);
        }
    }
}
```

So if you have already an existing **Customer** persisted and run **DeleteCustomerHandler**, the **Customer** will be updated, but its discriminator field won't!
Googling that, there is no way to update the discriminator field not going some hackish way like I do (running raw query manually to update the field).

Also, I need to use the **EntityManager->merge()** method to add manually initialized **DeletedCustomer** to internal UnitOfWork. Looks a little bit dirty too, and it's a deprecated method for Doctrine 3, so the question also is there a better way to handle my case?

So, to conclude all the questions:

1. Am I doing **Customer's** status change to **DeletedCustomer** completely wrong? I'm just trying to avoid **Customer** God Object, distinguish this Entity's bounded contexts, kinda that.
2. How to avoid **EntityManager->merge()** there? **AuthenticatedCustomer** comes from session (JWT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're absolutely right to want to avoid Customer turning into a god object. Inheritance is one way to do it, but using it for customers in different statuses can lead to problems.

The two key problems in my experience:

1. As new statuses emerge, will you keep adding different inherited entities?
2. What happens when you have a customer move through two different statuses, such as a customer that was a `NotActivatedCustomer` but is now a `DeletedCustomer`?

So I keep inheritance only when the inherited type is genuinely more specific type, where a given entity will only ever be one of those types for its entire lifecycle. Cars don't become motorbikes, for example.

I have two patterns for solving the problem differently to you. I tend to start with the first and move to the second.

```
interface DeletedCustomer
{
  public function getDeletedAt(): DateTime;
}

interface NotActivatedCustomer
{
  public function getCreatedAt(): DateTime;
}

class Customer implements DeletedCustomer, NotActivatedCustomer
{
  private $id;
  private $name;
  private DateTime $deletedAt;
  private bool $isActivated = false;

  public function getDeletedAt(): DateTime {...}
  public function getCreatedAt(): DateTime {...}
}

class DeletedCustomerRepository
{
  public function findAll(): array
  {
    return $this->createQuery(<<<DQL
      SELECT customer 
      FROM   Customer 
      WHERE  customer.deletedAt IS NOT NULL
    >>>)->getQuery()->getResults();
  }
}

class NotActivatedCustomerRepository
{
  public function findAll(): array
  {
    return $this->createQuery(<<<DQL
      SELECT customer 
      FROM   Customer 
      WHERE  customer.isActivated = false
    >>>)->getQuery()->getResults();
  }
}

class DeletedCustomerService
{
  public function doTheThing(DeletedCustomer $customer) {}
}
```

This reduces coupling, which is one of the main problems with god objects. So when the columns start to proliferate, I can move them off to real entities that join to the `Customer`. Components that refer to `DeletedCustomer` will still receive one.

The second pattern is event-sourcing-lite - have a many-to-one relationship with a "CustomerLifecycleEvent" entity. Query based on whether the customer has a "deleted" event. This second approach is much more complex, both to update and query. You can still have dedicated repositories that return entities like `DeletedCustomer`, but you'll need to do a bit more boilerplate.